# How to override validate on DirPartyTable lookup when input value is not found

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have a table with relation to DirPartyTable and Validate = Yes, the field EDT is DirPartyRecId, ignore EDTRelation = No.

During lookup, if input value is invalid, it will always prompt "
Unable to find a unique Global address book record corresponding to the entered values."

How do I remove this validation ?

I tried override lookup but the warning is coming right after performFormLookup

```
    SysReferenceTableLookup sysTableLookup = SysReferenceTableLookup::newParameters(tablenum(DirPArtyTable), sender);
    Query                   query = new Query();

    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(DirPArtyTable, Name));

    query.addDataSource(tablenum(DirPArtyTable));
    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
```

Comment: It sounds like you're saying, "I have a relation with validation enabled. And I want to disable validation." It seems like you're doing something unusual...create a custom field & lookup that doesn't have the validation or remove the validation.

Comment: Yes, and it seems not possible to do as i know.

Comment: Turn `Validation = Yes` to `No`? Or create a custom field. We need more information with what you're trying to accomplish. Generally if there's a relation, you want to keep the validation to prevent invalid data.